# Can you call highlight more than once? Need different colors for different matches

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, highlight, highlighting

I am working with text files and [Goyo](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim). I'd like to highlight two different kinds of notes delimited by brackets (one called "NOTE:" and the other "TODO:") in different colors.

I want to highlight everything within the brackets not just the words "NOTE" or "TODO". Below is the  code I have in my init.vim (I am using Neovim btw). It works fine if I try to highlight only one thing. But if I add line 220 and line 223 below (duplicating the call to highlight and the match) it doesn't highlight anything at all.

How can I highlight different matches ("Notes", "Todos" and anything else I might need later) with different colors?

```
   0 function! s:goyo_enter()
      212     Pencil
      213     Limelight
      219     highlight noteHi ctermfg=Magenta cterm=italic
    + 220     highlight todoHi ctermfg=Green cterm=italic
      222     match noteHi /\[\cNOTE:[^\]]*\]/
    + 223     match todoHi /\[\cTODO:[^\]]*\]/
      227 endfunction
```

I have also tried using matchadd() with a regex in quotes but the patterns don't match. If I remove everything leaving only "NOTE" and "TODO" in quote those do get highlighted, but it's not what I want.

I want to highlight everything within the brackets that start with those words. For example, *[TODO: Do something here.]* would have all the text inside the brackets highlighted.

```
 226     call matchadd("noteHi", "\[\cNOTE:[^\]]*\]")
 227     call matchadd("todoHi", "\[\cTODO:[^\]]*\]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### About `:match`

With the match command, you only get 3 match ids:

```
:match noteHi /\[\cNOTE:[^=]*\]/
:2match todoHi /\[\cTODO:[^=]*\]/
:3match what /ever/
```

Each time you call these commands for a particular id (1,2,3) you replace whatever was there before.  So you can have 3 different ones but that's it, only 3.  If you need more, use `matchadd()`.

### About `matchadd()`

The only problem with your code is that you use double quotes, in which backslashes must be escaped.  Simply use single quotes when dealing with patterns.

```
  call matchadd("noteHi", '\[\cNOTE:[^=]*\]')
  call matchadd("todoHi", '\[\cTODO:[^=]*\]')
```